# Растянуть блок на всю высоту Landing page

Tags: html, css

У меня на Landing'e блок типа хедера находится слева, и он должен продолжаться на весь landing.Уже пробовал по разному, но кроме фиксированной высоты и добавить идентичный блок каждой секции в голову ничего не приходит.

Заранее благодарен за помощь.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для отображения элемента на всю высоту страницы его нужно определять дочерним элементом родительского. Сам изначально долго ломал голову, а всё было просто - я не позиционировал родительский элемент как `position: relative;` Прилагаю пример:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
  position: relative; /* it's important */
}

.element {
  position: absolute; /* it's important */
  width: 80px;
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "element">
    
  </div>

</div>
```